# Retrieve Facebook ID from authdata in Parse - Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, userid

I made a mistake not saving the user FB id separately in Parse and now i am implementing a feature where i need the user Facebook ID. is it possible to access authData? My App is in production and have a large number of users. So not possible to save it again coz it will affect the current customers.

Comment: There is no direct link from a Facebook App Scopped ID to a Parse ID so you will not be able to retrieve that information. You will likely have to implement your logging of this data now and collect data for your current customers.